# Set symfony cache directory in parameters

Tags: php, symfony, security, docker, docker-compose

I'm building a docker environment for a Symfony application. I have a container per application with an attached data only container for the web root that is linked to the application server. As part of the security hardening for the infrastructure these data containers are set to read only, to prevent any remote code exploits. Each application then also has a side car container that allows logs to be written to.

Symfony currently writes the cache to the default `cache_dir` location of

```
${web_root}/app/cache/${env}
```

Which is in the read-only data container

when trying to boot the application I get this error

> Unable to write in the cache directory

Obviously as its in the write only container this will happen

I've set my log_path is set in parameters outside the read-only container in the read-write sidecar logging container of

```
/data/logs/symfony
```

which works fine.

I've read the Symfony cookbook on how to over ride the directory structure but it only advises on how to do this in `AppKernal.php` which I don't want to do as the paths may change dependant on if its in a `local/uat/prod` environment.

We feed Symfony different parameters from our build server depending on the environment we are deploying to so it makes sense to put this config in here.

does anyone know if its possible to override the cache dir in config rather than editing `AppKernal.php`

Comment: what's wrong with AppKernal.php? this is from their cookbook   

`return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/'.$this->environment.'/cache';`
env is already there and you can replace `dirname(__DIR__).'/var/'` with your custom config path

Comment: W're trying to keep code agnostic of env since the path changes more than $this->environment, it would require ifs or switch dependent on the env which we don't want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified example of a docker-compose yml file i'm using, with a read only parent  data container with 2 sidecar containers for caching and logging with :rw access that overrides a path that is contained with the read-only parent path

> docker-compose-base.yml

```
version: '2.0'

# maintainer james.kirkby@sonyatv.com
# @big narstie said "dont f*** up the #base"

services:

  # web server
  pitchapp-web:
    hostname: pitchapp-web
    depends_on:
      - pitchapp-dc   
      - pitchapp-log-sc
      - pitchapp-cache-sc
      - pitchapp-fpm
    volumes_from:
      - pitchapp-dc
      - pitchapp-log-sc:rw
      - pitchapp-cache-sc:rw
    links:
      - pitchapp-fpm
    build:
      args: 
        - APP_NAME=pitchapp  
        - FPM_POOL=pitchapp-fpm
        - FPM_PORT=9001
        - PROJECT=pitch
        - APP_VOL_DIR=/data/www
        - CONFIG_FOLDER=app/config
        - ENVIRONMENT=dev
        - ENV_PATH=dev   
      context: ./pitch
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    extends:
      file: "shared/dev-common.yml"
      service: dev-common-env
    env_file: 
      - env/dev.env

  # web data-container
  pitchapp-dc: 
    volumes:
      - /data/tmp:/data/tmp:rw      
      - /Sites/pitch/pitchapp:/data/www/dev/pitch/pitchapp/current:ro
    hostname: pitchapp-dc
    container_name: pitchapp-dc       
    extends:
      file: "shared/data-container-common.yml"
      service: data-container-common-env
    read_only: true
    working_dir: /data/www                      

  # web cache sidecar
  pitchapp-cache-sc:
    volumes:
      - /data/cache/pitchapp:/data/www/dev/pitch/pitchapp/current/app/cache/dev:rw
    hostname: pitchapp-cache-sc
    container_name: pitchapp-cache-sc
    extends:
      file: "shared/data-container-common.yml"
      service: data-container-common-env              
    read_only: false
    working_dir: /data/cache    

  # web log sidecar
  pitchapp-log-sc: 
volumes:
  - /data/log/pitchapp:/data/log:rw   
  - /data/log/pitchapp/symfony:/data/www/dev/pitch/pitchapp/current/app/logs:rw   
    build:
      args:
        - APP_NAME=pitchapp          
        - TARGET_SERVICE=pitchapp
    hostname: pitchapp-log-sc
    container_name: pitchapp-log-sc
    extends:
      file: "shared/logging-common.yml"
      service: logging-common-env
```

> data-container-common.yml

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  data-container-common-env:
    build:
      context: ./docker-data-container
      dockerfile: Dockerfile 
    image: jkirkby91/docker-data-container   
    env_file: 
      - env/data.env           
    restart: always
    privileged: false 
    tty: false
    shm_size: 64M
    stdin_open: true
```

> logging-common.yml

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  logging-common-env:
    build:
      context: ./logging
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: jkirkby91/docker-data-container    
    env_file: 
      - env/logging.env           
    restart: always
    working_dir: /data/log
    privileged: false 
    tty: false
    shm_size: 64M
    stdin_open: true       
    read_only: false
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm creating the cache file outside the container and using `-v` to mount the directory into the container

*$DIR is the current location*

*htdocs where the webfiles are*

```
docker run -d \
   -v $DIR/htdocs:/var/www/html \
   -v $DIR/cache_folder:/var/www/html/app/cache
```

Then make sure that the container is allowed to write into `cache_folder` . The advantage is that you're not loosing any data if you recreate the container. This will also overwrite the folder `/var/www/html/app/cache`

Another way you can do this is inside every container, but loose the setting with every restart

```
chmod -R 777 ${web_root}/app/cache/${env}
```

Comment: do you mean mount a data container on path that is also in side another read-only data container?

where using docker to manage acl on volumes like

    volumes_from:
      - myapp-dc:ro

will chmod overide these rules?

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean exactly but I'll update my answer with more codes

Comment: he wants `-v $DIR/htdocs:/var/www/html:ro`, it's actually interesting, if you have parent read-only and re-mount another folder inside the parent with r/w. could you test it?

Comment: I can confirm that it is working if you have `-v $DIR/htdocs:/var/www/html:ro`and another mount `-v $DIR/logs:/var/www/html/app/cache:rw`

Comment: yep beat me to it you can just remount a folder that already exists in a read-only container as a separate volume with :rw privileges and it works.

I'll provide a full answer and example with code example shortly.

Thanks for the idea!!!!